# Getting Mobile Device Context Parameters Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, mobile, mobile-safari, analytics

Is there any way through which one can get Mobile Device Context parameters like Battery level, Processor speed, Network Bandwidth etc through Javascript. I am working on a Mobile Analytic tool and need these parameters to process and present solution in a UI considering these fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for the HTML5 Battery Status API is limited (Firefox and Chrome). See this recent tutorial on SitePoint. http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-battery-status-api/

Here's another article from SitePoint re: the Network Information API. That also has limited support (Firefox and Chrome). http://www.sitepoint.com/use-network-information-api-improve-responsive-websites/

I am unaware of any accurate, cross-browser method to determine processor/hardware information via JavaScript.